# Adding data (not only text) to a multi column ListView (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am working on a WPF application in C# (.NET 4.0) where I have a ListView with a GridView that has two columns.

I dynamically want to add rows (in code). My dilemma is that only the first column will have regular text added to it. The second column will have an object that includes a multi column Grid with TextBlocks. (see link http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/listview.png/)

If I do what you would normally do when you want to enter text in all columns (ie. DisplayMemberBinding) all I get in the second column is the text "System.Windows.Grid", which obviously isn't what I want.

For reference if I just try to add the Grid object (with the TextBlocks) with the code listView1.Items.Add(grid1) (not using DisplayMemberBinding) the object gets added to the second column only (with the first column being blank) and not how it normally works with text where the same text ends up in all columns.

I hope my question is detailed enough and any help with this would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I have tried the following code, howeever every time I click the button to add a new row every single row gets updated with the same datatemplate. (ie. the **second** column always shows the same data on every row.)

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TEST.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="AAA"  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid Name="grid1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="374*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="129*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

code:

```
            public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ListView listView1 = new ListView();
    GridViewColumn viewCol2 = new GridViewColumn();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Style style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty,
            HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
        listView1.ItemContainerStyle = style;

        GridView gridView1 = new GridView();
        listView1.View = gridView1;
        GridViewColumn viewCol1 = new GridViewColumn();
        viewCol1.Header = "Option";
        gridView1.Columns.Add(viewCol1);
        viewCol2.Header = "Value";
        gridView1.Columns.Add(viewCol2);
        grid1.Children.Add(listView1);
        viewCol1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Option");
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();

        FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));

        Random random = new Random();
        int cols = random.Next(1, 6);
        int full = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory col1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ColumnDefinition));
            int partWidth = random.Next(0, full);
            full -= partWidth;
            col1.SetValue(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(partWidth, GridUnitType.Star));
            spFactory.AppendChild(col1);
        }
        if (full > 0)
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory col1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ColumnDefinition));
            col1.SetValue(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(full, GridUnitType.Star));
            spFactory.AppendChild(col1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory text1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            SolidColorBrush sb1 = new SolidColorBrush();
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    sb1.Color = Colors.Blue;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sb1.Color = Colors.Red;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sb1.Color = Colors.Yellow;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sb1.Color = Colors.Green;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sb1.Color = Colors.Purple;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    sb1.Color = Colors.Pink;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    sb1.Color = Colors.Brown;
                    break;
            }
            text1.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, sb1);
            text1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);
            spFactory.AppendChild(text1);
        }
        if (full > 0)
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory text1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            SolidColorBrush sb1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            text1.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, sb1);
            text1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, cols);
            spFactory.AppendChild(text1);
        }

        dataTemplate.VisualTree = spFactory;

        viewCol2.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;


        int rows = listView1.Items.Count + 1;
        listView1.Items.Add(new { Option = "Row " + rows });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use the `DisplayMemberBinding`, for complex content you can use the [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx), e.g.:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- This should display your grid if it is a property on your item called GridProperty -->
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding GridProperty}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I actually started to fool around with creating dynamic datattemplates but then I ended up with the second column in every row getting updated with the latest template created. I can't figure out how to make it so that each row can show different dynamic data in the second column.

Comment: You do not seem to have understood how datatemplates are supposed to be used, you appear to re-create a datatemplate every time you click the button while all your should do is add data to your source-collection which then is transformed into a visual representation by the static datatemplate.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. Sorry I am new to WPF. The problem is that I believe I can't use a static datatemplate since the controls in it will have to be dynamic for every row. Which is the best way to approach my problem then? Looking at the code above should hopefully atleast give a hint of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can do all kinds of dynamic things with **[data templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)**, the question is what kind of data you have.

Comment: Thank you H.B. Thanks to your code I finally managed to figure it out. :)